# Is the Debian Lenny PHP5 package secure?

Tags: php, debian, php5

For instance I'm running the php5 package using `apt-get install php5`. The reported version is: `PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny9`

However, there's currently listed 53 vulnerabilities for PHP/5.2.6 on CVE:

[Long link to CVE exploits list](http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list.php?vendor_id=74&product_id=128&version_id=57302&page=1&hasexp=0&opdos=0&opec=0&opov=0&opcsrf=0&opgpriv=0&opsqli=0&opxss=0&opdirt=0&opmemc=0&ophttprs=0&opbyp=0&opfileinc=0&opginf=0&cvssscoremin=0&cvssscoremax=0&year=0&)

Here's my question. Is `PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny9` patched against these vulnerabilities? (Perhaps that's what the `+lenny9` part is for?) How do I check?

For instance, how would I check whether [the recent EXIF vulnerability](http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/16261/) is patched in the current Debian Lenny package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look here: http://patch-tracker.debian.org/package/php5/5.2.6.dfsg.1-1+lenny9